# Access parameter name in range

Tags: hugo

Suppose a config toml:

```
[params.myList]
  item1 = "value1"
  item2 = "value2"
  item3 = "value3"
  item4 = "value4"

[params.myBadList]
  item1 = ["item1", "value1"]
  item2 = ["item2", "value2"]
  item3 = ["item3", "value3"]
  item4 = ["item4", "value4"]
```

What I would like is to iterate with range, such that I can access both the parameter name and the value, e.g.

```
{{ range .Site.Params.myList }}
  {{ .ParamName }} is {{ . }} <br>
{{ end }}
```

How can I access the current parameter name within range? The following works, but requires annoying redundancy.

```
{{ range .Site.Params.myBadList }}
  {{ index . 0 }} is {{ index . 1 }} <br>
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable names in `range` for index/key and their values, as per the 
[Intro](https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/#example-4-declaring-variable-names-for-a-map-elements-key-_and_-value)

```
{{ range $key, $value := $.Site.Params.myList }}
  {{ $key }}, {{ $value }}<br>
{{ end }}
```